# React Superagent-bluebird-promise with headers

Tags: reactjs, header, promise, bluebird, superagent

I would like to add headers to superagent bluebird promise in my React project , I ran across superagent-promise-headers (https://github.com/doron2402/superagent-promise-headers) and would like to use it.

Looking at their example I am confused with this syntax...

```js
          var request = require('superagent-promise-headers')({
          headers: {
              base: { 'content-service': 'Doron-Service' },
              get: { 'content-service-type': 'Doron-Service-GET' },
              post: { 'content-service': 'Doron-Service-POST' },
              del: { 'content-service': 'Doron-Service-DELETE' },
              put: { 'content-service': 'Doron-Service-PUT' }
          }
      });
```

I don't understand what is happening  and I would like to use it in my decryptImage function.

I am using mashape api and I need to add headers.  In their example:

```js
// These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/nodejs
unirest.post("https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "KEYHERE")
.field("focus[x]", "480")
.field("focus[y]", "640")
.field("image_request[altitude]", "27.912109375")
.attach("image_request[image]", fs.createReadStream("monkey.jpg"))
.field("image_request[language]", "en")
.field("image_request[latitude]", "35.8714220766008")
.field("image_request[locale]", "en_US")
.field("image_request[longitude]", "14.3583203002251")
.field("image_request[remote_image_url]", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/Mashape_logo.png")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
});
```

```js
    My Code
    
    import request from  'superagent-bluebird-promise'
    
    // should I use  'superagent-promise-headers' instead?  im confused here
    
    var ImageStore = Reflux.createStore({
    
    ..
    .
    .
      
         decryptImage(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var info = {}
        
            reader.onload = (output) => {
              request.post("https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests")
               ///  !!Here!!  
               ///  !!confused here too
                .header(
                  {
                  "X-Mashape-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                      "Accept": "application/json"
                    })
                    .send("image_request[locale]=en_US")
                    .send("image_request[longitude]=14.3583203002251")
                    .send("image_request[image]=reader")
                    .then(function (result) {
                            console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
this.info = result
                    },
                      function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    );
                }
            
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                return info
              },
            
              onAddImage(file) {
                var info = this.decryptImage(file);
              },
        });
    
    TLDR: Can someone show me how to set up headers with superagent-bluebird-promise? so I can call a 3rd party API service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it but it looks like you should do it like this.

```js
var request = require('superagent-promise-headers')({
    headers: {
        post: { 
          "X-Mashape-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Accept": "application/json" }
    }
});    
    // should I use  'superagent-promise-headers' instead?  im confused here
    
    var ImageStore = Reflux.createStore({
    
    ..
    .
    .
      
         decryptImage(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var info = {}
        
            reader.onload = (output) => {
              request.post("https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests")
               .send("image_request[locale]=en_US")
               .send("image_request[longitude]=14.3583203002251")
               .send("image_request[image]=reader")
               .then(function (result) {
                   console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
this.info = result
                    },
                      function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    );
                }
            
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                return info
              },
            
              onAddImage(file) {
                var info = this.decryptImage(file);
              },
        });
```

Comment: what is this code doing?

require('superagent-promise-headers')({
    headers: {
        post: { 
          "X-Mashape-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Accept": "application/json" }
    }
});    

I have never seen that syntax before,  can you translate it to ES6 for me?

Comment: Its from their example so I assume it is the way they expect it to work. You don't need to translate to es6 since it all gets translated back to common js anyway.